# How to get device token in order to use Firebase cloud messaging for Push Notifications in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, token, firebase

I want to test firebase fcm on my Magento 2 app. But I am not able to get a device token. How will I get the device token in Magento 2?

Comment: Can you show what errors are you facing while working ?